# How do I return an entire paged set from the Jira API using Ramda?

Tags: functional-programming, jira-rest-api, ramda.js

I'm using the Nodejs library for talking to Jira called jira-connector. I can get all of the boards on my jira instance by calling

```
jira.board.getAllBoards({ type: "scrum"})
  .then(boards => { ...not important stuff... }
```

the return set looks something like the following:

```
{ 
  maxResults: 50,
  startAt: 0,
  isLast: false,
  values:
   [ { id: ... } ]
}
```

then while *isLast === false* I keep calling like so:

```
jira.board.getAllBoards({ type: "scrum", startAt: XXX })
```

until *isLast* is true. then I can organize all of my returns from promises and be done with it.

I'm trying to reason out how I can get all of the data on pages with Ramda, I have a feeling it's possible I just can't seem to sort out the how of it.

Any help? Is this possible using Ramda?

Comment: I don't think there is something in Ramda that will specifically help.  You will probably need to write this slightly odd looping yourself.

Comment: It feels like a bad answer, I looked at using Rx as well and wrote a solution that still feels like I'm missing something. Maybe there isn't a cleaner way, but I still have that feeling...

Comment: Perhaps you could post your code as an answer to this, or as another question?  Someone might be able to suggest improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Rx attempt to make this better:

```
const pagedCalls = new Subject();

pagedCalls.subscribe(value => {
    jira.board.getAllBoards({ type:"scrum", startAt: value })
        .then(boards => {
            console.log('calling: ' + value);
            allBoards.push(boards.values);
            if (boards.isLast) {
                pagedCalls.complete()
            } else {
                pagedCalls.next(boards.startAt + 50);
            }

        });
})
pagedCalls.next(0);
```

Seems pretty terrible. Here's the simplest solution I have so far with a do/while loop:

```
let returnResult = [];
let result;
let startAt = -50;

do {

  result = await jira.board.getAllBoards( { type: "scrum", startAt: startAt += 50 })
  returnResult.push(result.values); // there's an array of results under the values prop. 

} while (!result.isLast)
```

Many of the interactions with Jira use this model and I am trying to avoid writing this kind of loop every time I make a call.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar today, calling the Gitlab API repeatedly until I had retrieved the entire folder/file structure of the project.  I did it with a recursive call inside a `.then`, and it seems to work all right.  I have not tried to convert the code to handle your case.

Here's what I wrote, if it will help:

```js
const getAll = (project, perPage = 10, page = 1, res = []) =>
  fetch(`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${encodeURIComponent(project)}/repository/tree?recursive=true&per_page=${perPage}&page=${page}`)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(xs => xs.length < perPage
            ? res.concat(xs)
            : getAll(project, perPage, page + 1, res.concat(xs))
         )
 
getAll('gitlab-examples/nodejs')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.warn)
```

The technique is pretty simple:  Our function accepts whatever parameters are necessary to be able to fetch a particular page and an additional one to hold the results, defaulting it to an empty array.  We make the asynchronous call to fetch the page, and in the `then`, we use the result to see if we need to make another call.  If we do, we call the function again, passing in the other parameters needed, the incremented page number, and the merge of the current results and the ones just received.  If we don't need to make another call, then we just return that merged list.

Here, the repository contains 21 files and folders.  Calling for ten at a time, we make three fetches and when the third one is complete, we resolve our returned Promise with that list of 21 items.

This recursive method definitely feels more functional than your versions above.  There is no assignment except for the parameter defaulting, and nothing is mutated along the way.

I think it should be relatively easy to adapt this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get all the boards using [rubico](https://github.com/richytong/rubico):

```js
import { pipe, fork, switchCase, get } from 'rubico'

const getAllBoards = boards => pipe([
  fork({
    type: () => 'scrum',
    startAt: get('startAt'),
  }),
  jira.board.getAllBoards,
  switchCase([
    get('isLast'),
    response => boards.concat(response.values),
    response => getAllBoards(boards.concat(response.values))({
      startAt: response.startAt + response.values.length,
    })
  ]),
])

getAllBoards([])({ startAt: 0 }) // => [...boards]
```

getAllBoards will recursively get more boards and append to `boards` until isLast is true, then it will return the aggregated `boards`.